# SqlException: Invalid column name (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I try to update a table column, but it fails. Here is the code for update on my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddDoctorsAppointment(string Start, string End, string Title, int? idPatient)
{
    Appointment appointmentDoc = new Appointment()
    {
        Start_appointment = Start,
        End_appointment = End,
        Title = Title,
        Type_of_appointment = "Doctors",
        Patient_Id = idPatient
    };
    db.Appointments.Add(appointmentDoc);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
}
```

Here is model of appointments

```
public partial class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Start_appointment { get; set; }
    public string End_appointment { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type_of_appointment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Patient_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to update I get this error:

[image: Screen]

I tried to find the column name `Patient_Id1`, but I don't have it in my project.

Cleaning and Rebuild didn't help. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you are using DB first approach. Go into your .edmx file and find the mapping for the Appointment class and for the Patient class. Somewhere in the properties there you will see exactly which properties are mapped to which columns and will be able to update this.

Comment: Certainly you have mapping problem in EDMX (shown by number suffix which EF trying to avoid duplicate foreign key) or having 2 different FK for the same PK (mapped twice). I think you need to have `ICollection` set for `Patient` class, then update model from DB.

Answer (score -1):

If it is DB first then you should update EDMX file by adding Patient_Id to the table Appointment then re-build solution.

If it is Code first then only add this db field to the Appointment table then run it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure db columns are properly matched with your edmx. Usually this error occurs when your edmx and database are not in sync

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me when I accidentally created a table with a space at the end of a column name. I updated the model and saw that EF added an underscore, that's how I caught the mistake. I removed, corrected, and updated the model again. That's when this error started.

After trying pretty much everything I completely deleted and recreated my model, cleaned the project. EVERYTHING. That's all it took and I was back in business!